# How can edit sections in a html file using php functions

Tags: php, html

i cant resolve the problem. how to change data using php in a admin panel which also required connections with database. The data from database aslo reflect in template

```
<?php function editSectionsByName($filename, $sectionName, $newData) {
  $fileContents = file_get_contents($filename);
  if ($fileContents === false) {
      echo "Error: Unable to read the file.\n";
      return;
  }
 
}
$filename = "template.html"; // Replace with your HTML file
$sectionName = "aboutus"; // Name of the sections to edit
$newData = ''; // Replace with your new section data

editSectionsByName($filename, $sectionName, $newData);


?>
```

Comment: You edit HTML with a [DOM parser](https://php.net/dom). But it's an unusual way to handle templating in PHP, you normally create templates with PHP code (or some dedicated templating engine like Twig) and you populate them using variables. What's the context here?